# Printing components on a Star TSP 100U

Tags: java, swing, printing

I'm trying to print a jscrollpane to a receipt thermal printer,a TSP100/143 USB.
The issue is that if i select A4 from the page setup after i click print it will print as if it is an A4 paper,it will have the A4 height.If i select 72mm x Receipt it will just spread the receipt to a huge height,i have to shut it down cuz it prints like full meters of page.

My receipt can be short or like meters long,depending on the amount of user entries,the scrollpane will expand.
Now,another issue is that it will only print the visible part of the scrollpane.

I really don't understand much from the printing part of java so could you please help me ?
I'm really stuck and i need to make this work as soon as possible.
I made this in Android and it was all good but java is so messy at this chapter,in my opinion.

Here are some screenshots and my printing code :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5l8ausvgwpztoui/Screenshot%202013-12-11%2023.25.34.png
A screenshot of how my application looks like,to make an ideea of what i want to do.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fnyigcieqf7eyi/2013-12-11%2023.24.10.jpg
As you can see,it spreads the content to be the height of an A4 paper.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pppez3dz2s3t709/2013-12-11%2023.32.42.jpg
Here,you can see that beside spreading it,it only shows the visible part of the scrollpane.

The printing code :

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PageFormat preformat = pjob.defaultPage();
preformat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
PageFormat postformat = pjob.pageDialog(preformat);

if (preformat != postformat) {
//Set print component
pjob.setPrintable(this, postformat);
if (pjob.printDialog()) {
    try {
        pjob.print();
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}}
}                                        

@Override
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int page_index)
        throws PrinterException {
    if (page_index > 0) {
        return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    // get the bounds of the component
    Dimension dim = jScrollPane2.getSize();
    double cHeight = dim.getHeight();
    double cWidth = dim.getWidth();

    // get the bounds of the printable area
    double pHeight = format.getImageableHeight();
    double pWidth = format.getImageableWidth();

    double pXStart = format.getImageableX();
    double pYStart = format.getImageableY();

    double xRatio = pWidth / cWidth;
    double yRatio = pHeight / cHeight;

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.translate(pXStart, pYStart);
    g2.scale(xRatio, yRatio);
    jScrollPane2.paint(g2);

    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;

}
```

How can i fix it or are there any other ways i can simply print to a TSP100/143 USB ? JavaPOS is really weird and looks complicated,besides being old,not updated and unable to arrange stuff as you want.

Thanks and have a great day !

EDIT : Well,it all works better now.I changed the ' double yRatio = pHeight / cHeight;' to  'double yRatio = pHeight / 0.75;' and i changed the printed view to the jpanel inside the scrollpane and now it's all good. It prints even if not visible and it doesn't scale it if i select 72xReceipt.

Thanks MadProgrammer.You were on every question i searched regarding this topic,you helped a lot !

Comment: 1- You may need to create a custom `Page` and `PageFormat` to meet the needs of the printing, including calculating the "potential" height on the paper; 2- I wouldn't scale the scroll pane...in fact, I wouldn't even bother printing the scrollpane but would focus on printing the view of the scrollpane; 3- Make sure you are sizing the component to fit withing the viewable area of the output (within the `print` method

Comment: Yea,i tried a couple of minutes ago switching to printing the panel instead of the scrollpane and it now prints the whole thing.The issue now is that it expands and contracts the rows depending on how many there are so that they all fit the A4 page.If i switch to 72m x Receipt it will just print a huge height and it will expand every words height by a lot.

Comment: That seems to because you are scaling the image.  I doubt that Java can predict how long it should  make the page, or when a new page is required...

Comment: And how could i do that ? How can i tell java hey,i have this amount of rows or the view has this height,make the receipt this height ?

Comment: That depends on lot of things, and much of it needs to be pre-calculated.  My personal preference would be to calculate the number of lines based on the pixel width of the page and the font metrics of the output...